# Windows 7 XP mode - ODBC host connection

Tags: windows-xp, odbc, windows-7

I have a legacy application that installs fine in Windows XP mode on Windows 7 64 bit, but it requries an ODBC connection.  Is it possible to have the XP mode application use the host Windows 7 ODBC configuration (and Oracle drivers)?

Comment: It seems very unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. They are considered separate systems, coincidentally running on the same hardware at the same time.